# dataframe combine row values to a list without NaN

Tags: python, pandas, list, na, tolist

I want to combine values in each row to a list and add a column on the dataframe. But some columns have `NaN`, how can I remove `NaN` in the list?

df

```
A  B  C
2  3  NaN
1  3  1
3  4  6
```

Expected output

```
A  B  C    D
2  3  NaN  [2, 3]
1  3  1    [1, 3, 1]
3  4  6    [3, 4, 6]
```

I know we can use `dropna()` in a dataframe, but in this case of combining row values, how can we use `dropna()`?

My code is here, I tried `dropna()` after `tolist()` and `df`, they did not output correctly

```
df['D'] = df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack (this eliminates NaN), groupby index from initial frame and then aggregate to lis

```
df['D']=df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)



   A  B    C                D
0  2  3  NaN       [2.0, 3.0]
1  1  3  1.0  [1.0, 3.0, 1.0]
2  3  4  6.0  [3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```